# Trying to save image to Photo album with custom name in iOS

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an iOS application where I am saving an image to my photos folder to my iPad.  However, what I would like to do is store the image with a custom name (e.g. using the date and time stamp for when the image was actually captured), so that it would be easier for it to be retrieved in the future.

My code at the moment for storing my images is as follows:

```
- (IBAction)imageCapture:(id)sender {
    
    UIImage *myImage = [_imageView currentImage];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(myImage, nil, nil, nil);
        
}
```

I am able to store my image, but how do I name the image prior to storing it (e.g. "082620131100am.png"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you cannot override any image/video in the user's photo library, you will not be able to give the the file a specific filename.

You can add some metadata to your image if you use the method: [`writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009722-CH1-SW1), but you will not be able to set the filename.

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt reply.  If this is the case, is it possible for me to load/retrieve an image based on this metadata?

Comment: I'm guess you could, but you will have to loop thru all the image and request the meta data. You could also just shave the media asset URL>

Comment: If I want to replace same images then how to do it with photo library?Is there any way to do this.I am calling webservices to get images and saving it in photo library but I is creating copy of images because webservice is calling no. of time.

Comment: @DeviPhone26, please start your own question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Started new question now.Please check if you can help.Thanks.