# how to save UIImage in photos album using a custom name for the image

Tags: ipad, uiimage

i am trying to save UIImage in the photos album of iPad with a custom name for each UIImage. I searched a lot and i realised that it is possible if i save them at the documents directory but not in the photos album. I was wondering if you could suggest a solution for that , please? Thank you in advance, best regards

Comment: Possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447084/trying-to-save-image-to-photo-album-with-custom-name-in-ios

Answer (score 1):

To save it with a custom name I would use the following code:

```
// I do this in the didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img method

// Build NSData in memory from the btnImage...
NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0);

// Save to the default Apple (Camera Roll) folder.   
[imageData writeToFile:@"/private/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/customImageFilename.jpg" atomically:NO];
```

In order to save an **screenshot in the device in a custom album name** use the following code:

```
- (void)createScreenshotAndSaveInACustomAlbum {
    DebugLog(@"");

    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    } else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
    }

    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [library addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName:@"My Photo Album" resultBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group) {

        // Checks if group previously created
        if(group == nil){

            // Enumerate albums
            [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum
                               usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *g, BOOL *stop)
             {
                 // If the album is equal to our album
                 if ([[g valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName] isEqualToString:@"My Photo Album"]) {

                     // Save image
                     [library writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) metadata:nil
                                           completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {

                                               // Then get the image asseturl
                                               [library assetForURL:assetURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                                                        // Put it into our album
                                                        [g addAsset:asset];
                                                    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {

                                                    }];
                                           }];

                 }
             } failureBlock:^(NSError *error){ }];
        } else {
            // Save image directly to library
            [library writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) metadata:nil
                                  completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {

                                      [library assetForURL:assetURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                                               [group addAsset:asset];

                                           } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) { }];
                                  }];
        }

    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) { }];
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer , however i tried that and i could not find where the picture is saved. I checken in the Camera Roll , in the Pictures b, but i could not find it . I do not use the camera actually , but i take screenshots and i want to save them in the photos album of ipad. I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I heard that there is a mechanism with which i can change the names that pictures take with some code. I was wondering if you could provide me some code that solves this problem, please? Thank you in  advance.

Comment: It is not possible to set a filename once you save a photo in the photo album (since the photo album app doesn't show names), the only thing you can do is to set a name for the folder as I described in the code above.