# Swift 3 : Download image and save it with name to Photo library

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview, photos

I want to **download an Image and save it with Timestamp name.**

Below is code that I’ve used :

```
@IBAction func btnDownload_Clicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let timeStamp = String(Date().ticks)
        print("timeStamp : \(timeStamp)")

         UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imgQRCode.image!, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
    }

//MARK: - Add image to Library
    func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
        if let error = error {
            let objAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            objAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
            present(objAlert, animated: true)
        }
        else {
            let objAlert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: saveQR, preferredStyle: .alert)
            objAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
            present(objAlert, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

However, the issue with above code is that how to set Timestamp as name for Image?

I’ve tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40723682/1753005) wherein image is downloaded by not visible in Photos app.

Any quick fix?

Comment: As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/18447209/4601900 You can not give File name , but you can give metadata

Comment: @MikeAlter : Any solution by which image is saved in Photos Album along with custom name?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve ? may someone here can help you to find alternative solution :)

Comment: @MikeAlter : I want to save the image on press on download button. This image should be visible in Photos app of iPhone with name as Timestamp.

Comment: @JayprakashDubey : It is not possible as `Photo Library` doesn't show the name of any image! So Why you want to do so ? you can set it's metadata, and you can retrieve that metadata also when you pick image from photo library.

Comment: As it looks like not possible with current SDK, You  should create album in photo library and save image into it. may be helpful